# Remove browser accessibility outline from pseudo element

Tags: css

I have a button which has an `:after` which I need to add an `outline:none` to, but it only works when I add it to the button itself. Any idea how I can remove the outline from the `:after only?

```
.dropdown-button:global(.is-active):after {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide sufficient code to let us reproduce the issue, then we can try to help :D

Comment: Browsers don't apply outlines to pseudo-elements. They may take them into account when drawing outlines around their originating elements, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot remove the outline from the element that the `:after` is in.

As an alternative, I added it as a `:before` to the element below it. Looks the same.